# A folder inside views folder, Routing and/or Controller error in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

I'm new to CI, I barely managed to start my own website and had it running for a while now, I had all the views structure as the CI guide, but then I want to put a php file called igniel.php inside a folder called "vcard" **inside** the pages folder.

The problem is, when I try to load it using a full path like :

```
http://example.com/application/views/pages/vcard/igniel.php
```

its showing up nicely, but once I use

```
http://example.com/igniel (without the php)
```

it will show a 404 error.

here is my Pages.php content :

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
             if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
```

and here is my routes.php content :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I've tried to googling and use a few suggestion around but still no luck...

many thanks in advance.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sopposed to call view file. Instead you should make request through controllerwhich is meant to call specific file. So you never want to call (nor I am sure how you succeeded in request with that URL):

```
http://example.com/application/views/pages/vcard/igniel.php
```

but

```
http://example.com/pages/view/igniel
```

(withouth the extension).

You should follow basic example from CI documentation. In your case it means you are trying to use subdirectory vcard with same code in controller that doesn't fit your needs.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
        elseif ( $page == 'igniel' )// your page is in subdirectory
        {
            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/nav');
            $this->load->view('pages/vcard/'.$page);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/nav');
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

But, if you want to call it like:

```
http://example.com/igniel
```

You have to change line in controller to include that file within it's path as described in `elseif` line.
Routing should take place like:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

If you have more subdirectories, you have to fit code in controller to aproach those as I describe it here for you.

Comment: this just change my home page to igniel.php lol... I mean, I need to access my igniel.php file which in pages/vcard by typing http://example.com/igniel...

Comment: Can you double confirm that you see regular page when you type `http://example.com/application/views/pages/vcard/igniel.php` in url?

Comment: I've added a route to $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/vcard/$1'; but still 404 error...

Comment: Have you changed your own `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';` for `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`?

Comment: Something is very wrong with your CI installation because noone's supposed to achieve that URL. `base_url('application/views/vcard/igniel.php')` can't be achieved in correct installation of CI. Check again [General Topics](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/index.html).

Comment: alright then, I'll re install the CI first. thanks anyway :)